# YouTube & Captcha

Tags: c#, youtube, captcha

I create a YoutubeRequest using the following:

```
settings = New YouTubeRequestSettings("appname", devkey", user, pass)
request = New YouTubeRequest(settings)
```

But Sometimes i have CaptchaRequiredException. How can I handle this Exception and get captcha URL/IMG etc, Could anyone help out, i use c#? Thanks

Comment: I have no experience in the matter, so don't quote me. but the point of a captcha is to PREVENT automation.  If you are hitting a captcha reuqired exception, i would think that you are going about this the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
    settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("appname", devkey", user, pass);
    request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
}
catch (CaptchaRequiredException ex)
{
    //do something with ex.Url and ex.Token
}
```

See [Google's documentation](http://google-gdata.googlecode.com/svn/branches/NET2.0/clients/cs/docs/generated/html/AllMembers_T_Google_GData_Client_CaptchaRequiredException.htm).

Comment: I try use this code:

    try
    {
        settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("appname", devkey", user, pass);
        request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
    
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
        yourequest.Insert(video.ComplaintUri, c); // on this line i got error
    }
    catch (CaptchaRequiredException ex)
    {
        //do something with ex.Url and ex.Token
    }
      catch (GDataRequestException e)
    {
      //and he move to GDataRequestException, not to CaptchaRequiredException
    }